# classpath problems with JDK 1.8.0_112 and windows 7

Tags: java

What class path should i use to avoid could not find main class error. I am using  `jdk 1.8.0_112` and windows 7.
I have tried `(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib;.;)` but its not working error is still there.
My **`javac welcome.java`** command executes properply but command to execute class files are not working properly i.e., **java welcome**. 
My code is running perfect on netbeans but i have problem with command prompt.
Anyone please tell me what classpath should i set to avoid this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct classpath depends on where your application class file / files are, where any dependencies are.

You DO NOT need to put `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin` on the classpath.  It contains nothing that the classloader could load ...

You DO NOT need to put `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib` on the classpath.  The `java.exe` command puts the libries in that directory onto the bootstrap classpath automatically.

The classpath should NOT end with a `;`.  The `;` is a separator, not a terminator.

For information on what to put on your classpath read the following Oracle documentation:

- [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

(I am not going to tell you / guess what it should be because that depends on information that you haven't given us.  However if you read and understand the above, you will be able to figure out what to do.  In your specific case, and others.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting the classpath : 

classpath=%classpath%;.;..;

java welcome

Also you can use -cp option : 

java -cp . welcome